# Reading Large CSV and splitting it into smaller chunks

Tags: python, sql, pandas, csv, pandasql

I'm trying to read and analyze a large csv file (11.5 GB) using python. And then use Power BI to create some visuals around it. But everytime I run any command line or even making changes to the dataframe in Power BI, it takes about 20-30 mins between each change.

One of the column heading is `DeviceID`. I would like to split the large CSV into multiple csv files so that each file will have data that belongs to the one unique  `DeviceID` value.

Currently the dataframe looks like this in the single `Full.csv` file looks like this:

```
DeviceID    AreaName     Longitude    Latitude
12311       Dubai        55.55431     25.45631
12311       Dubai        55.55432     25.45634
12311       Dubai        55.55433     25.45637
12311       Dubai        55.55431     25.45621
12309       Dubai        55.55427     25.45627
12309       Dubai        55.55436     25.45655
12412       Dubai        55.55441     25.45657
12412       Dubai        55.55442     25.45656
```

After running the code, the single `Full.csv` file should produce 3 csv files: `12311.csv` , `12309.csv` , `12412.csv` with each looking like this:

```
DeviceID    AreaName     Longitude    Latitude
12311       Dubai        55.55431     25.45631
12311       Dubai        55.55432     25.45634
12311       Dubai        55.55433     25.45637
12311       Dubai        55.55431     25.45621
```

AND

```
DeviceID    AreaName     Longitude    Latitude
12309       Dubai        55.55427     25.45627
12309       Dubai        55.55436     25.45655
```

AND

```
DeviceID    AreaName     Longitude    Latitude
12412       Dubai        55.55441     25.45657
12412       Dubai        55.55442     25.45656
```

I read that the best way to deal with large files in python is to use the pandasql module. Would I be able to achieve what I have described above using pandsql?

Thanks

Comment: How many unique `DeviceID`s are there totally in your dataframe? What is the memory of your machine?

Comment: I'm not sure how many unique `DeviceID`s there are. Even a simple `df.head()` or `df.describe` command is taking ages to run! The memory of my machine is 16GB

Comment: What's the separator of your CSV?? Multiple spaces??
If no, please specify what's the real separator

Comment: The seperators are mainly commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the column heading is DeviceID. I would like to split the large CSV into multiple csv files so that each file will have data that belongs to the one unique DeviceID value.

I do not think that this will speed up your process in PowerBI, do you do your calculation in PowerQuery or in PowerBI themself?

But anyway, you can create a list of your unique values for DeviceID:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Full.csv')
uniquelist = list(df['DeviceID'].unique())
```

and then split it based on this list and save it into csv files:

```
for i in uniquelist:
   i = df.loc[df['DeviceID'] == i]
   i.to_csv
```

Answer (score 3):

If python it's not mandatory, you could use Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller).

Starting from

```
DeviceID,AreaName,Longitude,Latitude
12311,Dubai,55.55431,25.45631
12311,Dubai,55.55432,25.45634
12311,Dubai,55.55433,25.45637
12311,Dubai,55.55431,25.45621
12309,Dubai,55.55427,25.45627
12309,Dubai,55.55436,25.45655
12412,Dubai,55.55441,25.45657
12412,Dubai,55.55442,25.45656
```

and running

```
mlr --csv --from input.csv put -q 'tee > $DeviceID.".csv", $*'
```

you will have these 3 files

```
#12311.csv
DeviceID,AreaName,Longitude,Latitude
12311,Dubai,55.55431,25.45631
12311,Dubai,55.55432,25.45634
12311,Dubai,55.55433,25.45637
12311,Dubai,55.55431,25.45621

#12412.csv
DeviceID,AreaName,Longitude,Latitude
12412,Dubai,55.55441,25.45657
12412,Dubai,55.55442,25.45656

#12309.csv
DeviceID,AreaName,Longitude,Latitude
12309,Dubai,55.55427,25.45627
12309,Dubai,55.55436,25.45655
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, can you read it in in chunks, or do you need the whole dataframe? This will help considerably.

```
import pandas as pd

row_count = 1000
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=row_count): 
    print(chunk.head()) # process it
```

Have you considered taking the CSV and putting it into an SQL database? Would speed things up a bit. You'll be able to index columns, do basic aggregations via SQL, and get the needed subsamples into Pandas for more complex processing using a simple `pd.read_sql`. You're going to be able to calculate faster with the SQL db. Second, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: Well, the csv file is actually a file that is made up of 70 merged files. I had to do that to make sure that all the `DeviceID`s are collated in one dataframe so that I can filter them later. One thing I forgot to mention, is that there aren't any column headings in the CSV file. I've attempted to run this command to assign new headings: `df = pd.read_csv('out.csv', header = None, engine='python', error_bad_lines=False)
df.columns = ["LicensePlate", "ID1", "CompanyName", "Long", "Lat", "Data_Time", "Emirate", 'OriginArea', "Road"]`

Comment: The memory of my machine is 16GB

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre><code>
import pandas as pd
full=pd.read_csv('path of the file')
f12311=full[full['DeviceID']==12311]
f12309=full[full['DeviceID']==12309]
f12412=full[full['DeviceID']==12412]
f12311.to_excel('path where to save the file')
f12309.to_excel('path where to save the file')
f12412.to_excel('path where to save the file')
</code></pre>
```

NOTE: just make sure that the dtype of 'DeviceID' column is 'int64'
if its not int, you can convert the same using code:

```
<pre><code>
full['DeviceID']=full['DeviceID'].astype('int64')
</code></pre>
```